# After doing a SQLAlchemy update(), is there a way to get the changed values?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

After calling update(), I know that the return value has a .rowcount attribute that will reveal how many rows were changed. Is there a way to get the actual new *values* that they were changed to?

For example, if I do the SQLAlchemy equivalent of:

```
UPDATE t SET x=x+1 WHERE y=z
```

...is there a way to get the new value for x? Or do I have to do a SELECT?

Answer (score 3):

The `ResultProxy` has two methods, `last_updated_params()` which returns a dictionary of every bind parameter value sent with the statement execution, as well as a collection `postfetch_cols()`, a list of columns for which an inline SQL expression was embedded in the UPDATE (for which you'd have to post-SELECT the values).  These collections are only populated for single-statement executions, not "executemany" calls which pass multiple sets of parameters along.

Comment: Can you give an example of the post-`SELECT` embedded SQL expression? Not sure where I'd even add that on to my `update` object.